# Move code from haml template to view helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, dry, view-helpers

This is probably easy. I have the following lines in my haml view template. I want to move this into a helper method because i have to repeat the same lines of code in the same view

```
Do Something when
%b
 this happens
after this
```

How do i move this into a helper method?

This is what i have and this doesn't work

```
def summary
  "Do Something when" + haml_tag(:b) +  " after this"
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `capture_haml` to get the processed `haml_tag` value itself and append it to other text.

```
def the_helper
  "Do Something when".html_safe +
  capture_haml do
    haml_tag :b, 'this happens'
  end +
  "after this".html_safe
end
```

Otherwise, `haml_tag` directly writes to the view, probably not what you expected.

edit: Added `html_safe` for the strings...  This can be moved around the whole block, or handled in the view...

Comment: hah!! html_safe!! i always forget that this method exists. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

So if the directory in which your view is in is called 'directory' then you would just create a file in the helper directory called 'directory_helper.rb' and in that just add whatever methods you'd like.

Comment: I am sorry for not being clear. I am familiar with how the helper works and how to call it in the view. I am having problems with writing haml in the helper.

Comment: It's okay. And ahhh gotcha.

Comment: Have you checked out the example here: http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/Haml/Helpers.html#haml_tag-instance_method?